# `playVideo' does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new on C#, so I'm not sure what this error means.
`playVideo' does not implement interface member`Vuforia.ITrackableEventHandler.OnTrackableStateChanged(Vuforia.TrackableBehaviour.Status, Vuforia.TrackableBehaviour.Status)'
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Vuforia;

public class playVideo : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler{

    public VideoClip videoToPlay;
    public GameObject cubeObject;
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged (TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus) {
        Debug.Log (newStatus);
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Status Changed");
            videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer> ();
            audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource> ();

            videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
            audioSource.playOnAwake = false;

            videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;

            videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

            videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack (0, true);
            videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource (0, audioSource);

            videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
            videoPlayer.Prepare ();


            videoPlayer.Play ();
            audioSource.Play ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you implement the `ITrackableEventHandler` interface, the function to implement takes two parameters not one.

Replace

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged (TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
```

with

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
```

Refer to the `ITrackableEventHandler` interface [*source code*](https://github.com/mtysgithub/Qualcomm.Vuforia.UnityExtensions/blob/master/ITrackableEventHandler.cs) for more information.